# ¿Cómo licencio mi software a MIT?

Tags: licencias

¿Cómo se licencia un software a MIT? Estoy en un proceso de licenciar mi software y no sé como o qué hacer para hacerlo. He visto cómo se puede licenciar un software a GPL.

> La GPL de GNU indica que se debe colocar un aviso como éste al
>   principio de cada fichero con código fuente:
>
> Copyright (C)
>
> This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
>   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
>   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at
>   your option) any later version.
>
> This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
>   WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
>   General Public License for more details.
>
> You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
>   along with this program.  If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/

Comment: Aquí tienes info bastante interesante http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352/qu%C3%A9-consideraciones-deber%C3%ADa-tener-en-cuenta-antes-de-incluir-una-librer%C3%ADa-open que puede ayudarte a entender que licencia te conviene utilizar.

Comment: Gracias, detalle sumamente bien cada licencia y sus conceptos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que incluir este archivo junto al resto de tu código:

https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

Puedes especificar al principio de cada archivo que la licencia es MIT, pero no lo considero obligatorio.

> This software is MIT licensed (see LICENSE)

Esto es genérico y vale para cualquier licencia de software.

Comment: o que bien. muchas gracias !

Comment: otra consulta que quizas tu sepas: si uso un framework con licencia MIT, el archivo lo debo acumular con mi licencia? o es otro archivo a parte?

Comment: ¿"Usar" en este caso significa que estás distribuyendo ese código junto con el tuyo, o simplemente lo estás llamando o enlazando de alguna manera? En cualquier caso la licencia de tu código debería ser un archivo aparte.

Comment: A ok, claro lo estoy usando. Pues veré como nombro esos archivos de licencias para diferenciarlas.

Comment: En realidad tengo una ensalada de licencias en mi software... es de preocuparse cuando mi proyecto tendrá licencia MIT? (todas las licencias que uso son opensource)

Comment: Me autorespondo. No es de preocuparse si dejo las licencias estipuladas en las respectivas librerías.