# ¿Como generar un vídeo desde un audio e imágenes con PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Me gustaría saber como generar un vídeo a partir de imágenes y audio subido desde php.

```
<?php
  $exito = 0;
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    foreach ($_FILES['imgToUpload']['name'] as $i => $name) {
      if (strlen($_FILES['imgToUpload']['name'][$i]) > 1) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i], 'upload/'.$name)) {
          $exito=1;
        }
      }
    }
    if (strlen($_FILES['audioupload']['name']) > 1) {
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audioupload']['tmp_name'], 'upload/audioPrincipal.mp3')) {
        $exito=2;
      }
    }


    if (strlen($_FILES['audio2upload']['name']) > 1) {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audio2upload']['tmp_name'], 'upload/audioSecundario.mp3');
    }


  }
  if ($exito >= 2) {
    echo "<p style='color: green'>Subida con &eacute;xito</p>";
  }


 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Imagenes: <input name="imgToUpload[]" id="imgToUpload" type="file" multiple="" /><br>
        Audio: <input type="file" name="audioupload" value="audioupload" id="audioupload"><br>
        Audio secundario(opcional): <input type="file" name="audio2upload" value="audio2upload" id="audio2upload"><br>
        <!-- Audio secundario reducirle el volumen sobre el otro audio -->
        <input type="submit" value="Generar">
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Revisa este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216520/merging-audio-and-images-to-create-a-video-using-php tiene informacion que te puede servir

Comment: No es demasiado amplia :/

Comment: @JuanPinzón esa forma no te permite controlar la duración de cada slide. Fijate mi respuesta.

Comment: md, estoy seguro que yo había votado por cerrar una pregunta muy similar a esta. _pero no la encuentro en mis acciones..._

Answer (score 5):

### Usa `ffmpeg`.

Si bien es posible hacerlo de otras formas, [`ffmpeg`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) es la herramienta de facto (ademas de ser gratuita) para procesar video y audio. Como tiene licencia GNU hay algunas restricciones de como distribuir, pero en un sitio web (que queda en modalidad SaaS, [ver esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/438/25)) es perfectamente legal usarlo.

Lo que tienes que hacer es:

#### 1 - Subir las imágenes y audios a alguna ubicación bien conocida dentro del server.

#### 2 - Crear un archivo de texto con el formato `concat` de ffmpeg. Ejemplo:

```
file '/ruta/a/animales.png'
duration 5
file '/ruta/a/palomas.png'
duration 1
file '/ruta/a/perros.png'
duration 3
file '/ruta/a/gatos.png'
duration 2
```

Ten en cuenta que `duration` esta en segundos, se refiere al `file` inmediato anterior y puedes usar valores decimales (ej: 0.5 que seria medio segundo)

Aqui esta la documentacion del [formato concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat)

#### 3 - Lanzar el proceso (puedes usar [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)) para hacer el video:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i comandos.txt -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4
```

Donde `comandos.txt` es el archivo creado en el punto 2, y `video.mp4` es el video resultante.

Nota: lo he usado con imágenes del mismo tamaño, de las cuales sale las dimensiones del vídeo (imganes 1920 x 1080 generan un vídeo full HD). Si necesitas re-escalar el vídeo ver [aquí](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20(resizing)%20with%20ffmpeg).

#### 4 - Agregarle la pista de audio al vídeo (que puedes crear de forma similar, usando un `mp3` de salida)

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 output.mp4
```

Donde `video.mp4` es el archivo creado en el punto 3, `audio.mp3` es el audio a agregar y `output.mp4` es el resultado final.

#### Mas información

Te dejo estas referencia que son para mi la guia de trabajo con `ffmpeg`.

- Slideshow en la wiki de FFMPEG -> http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow
- Desarrollo con FFMPEG -> http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html
- La wiki: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/

Comment: Voy a probar, muchas gracias por la ayuda ^^.

Comment: @rnd excelente respuesta.

Comment: En el paso 2 la duración  tiene que sumar 10? como establezco la resolución del video?
Gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: @Hamwen fijta en mi edicion.