# ¿Cuál es la legislación española relativa a los derechos de autor y las licencias del software?

Tags: licencias

Una vez que empiezas en el mundo del desarrollo, empiezas a hacer tus proyectos, etc llega ese momento en el que te preguntas como proteger y distribuir tus creaciones.

Actualmente ya tengo algún que otro pequeño proyecto funcional. Me gustaría empezar a publicarlos pero quiero que al publicarlos mi autoria quede reflejada y que dicho software se distribuya bajo alguna licencia.

Tras leer e informarme, he llegado a la conclusión de que en Estados Unidos, por el simple hecho de desarrollar un software este ya tiene derechos de autor que protegen la autoria del desarrollador. También, por lo que he podido entender tras leer y leer es que cualquier desarrollador en Estados Unidos puede crear su propia licencia y añadirla a su proyecto/software. Desde ese momento ese software tiene los derechos de autor del desarrollador y la licencia creada por el mismo.

Sin embargo, sobre esta misma situación en España a penas he sido capaz de encontrar información. ¿Tenemos la misma política o se ha de hacer algo para aplicar los derechos de autor al software que he creado?

A la hora de distribuirlo, ¿puedo crear mi propia licencia o coger una licencia open-source para distribuir el software?

Espero que podais contarme vuestras experiencias relativas al tema. Como enfrentarme a estas dos incógnitas que me surgen al querer publicar mi software.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio raaowx!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta, para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Comment: Relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/363/74